# Facebook iFrame APP not working in IE, works on every other browser

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, iframe

So im getting a blank page when loading this page within an iFrame on Internet explorer, every other browser works fine..

I have also tried using p3p headers as other people have suggested, but to no avail.

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
require ("config.php");
require ("fb_config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Login handler</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <?//=$user?>
  <?php


if($user == 0) {
echo "You are not logged into facebook. Nice try.";
}else{


$query = "SELECT id,fb_id,login_ip,login_count,activated,sitestate FROM login WHERE fb_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login SET id = '', fb_id ='" .mysql_real_escape_string($user). "', name = '" .rand(10000000000000000,99999999999999999999). "', signup =NOW() , password = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($pass). "', state = '0', mail = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']). "',location='".mysql_real_escape_string($randomlocation)."',location_start='".mysql_real_escape_string($randomlocation)."', signup_ip='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."',ref='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ref'])."', activation_id = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($activation_link). "',activated='2', killprotection = '$twodayprot',gender='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["gender"]). "'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    }


        //if($row['fb_id']  != $user){
        //echo "Your facebook ID: $user is NOT in the MW DB.";
        //exit();
        //}else{


        if(empty($row['login_ip'])){
        $row['login_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }else{

        $ip_information = explode("-", $row['login_ip']);

        if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip_information)) {   
        $row['login_ip'] = $row['login_ip'];
        }else{  
        $row['login_ip'] = $row['login_ip']."-".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        }

$update_login = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET login_count=login_count+'1' WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'")
or die(mysql_error());

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET userip='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."',login_ip='".mysql_real_escape_string($row['login_ip'])."',login_count='0' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'")
or die(mysql_error());


if ($row['sitestate'] == 0){
header("location: home.php");
} elseif ($row['sitestate'] == 2) {
header("location: killed.php?id={$row['id']}&encrypted={$row['password']}");
} else {
header("location: banned.php?id={$row['id']}&encrypted={$row['password']}");
}

}// id check.


?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing the first two lines of the HTML markup to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
Not sure if this will help, but AFAIK Internet Explorer is sensitive to the doctype.

Comment: @Pateman Just tried this it still doesn't work, just a blank canvas on IE :(

Comment: There's nothing echoed in this script, so how could you possibly expect something to display? Have you checked if the redirects work?

Comment: @Pateman It should be setting the session & sending me to home.php which it doesn't do.. and it should not be a blank canvas as in a white page, The css should be doing what its supposed to and giving the page a background colour

Comment: Was this fixed? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing p3p headers causing your browser not to accept cookies from Facebook on your site.

See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx

or http://www.admon.org/how-to-implement-p3p-http-headers-for-cross-site-cookies/ for more information.

Comment: The second link helped for me: header('P3P: CP="CURa ADMa DEVa PSAo PSDo OUR BUS UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"')

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line that references your external css file and see if your page loads?

I just solved a similar problem I had. I had the correct p3p headers set up and I narrowed the problem down to css.

The problematic css style was a `position:relative;` on the html,body element - removing this fixed the problem of Facebook showing my iframe as a blank page.

If removing all the CSS displays something on your page, then you may need to add your CSS step-by-step to find out the culprit as some other kind of css sytle may break the page.